# ¿Como dar estilo al primer ítem seleccionado desde un Combobox con Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify

Buen día comunidad les comento, estoy intentando agregar un estilo al primer ítem que se selecciona a través de un `Combobox Component` usando `Vuetify`, recordando que siempre y cuando los demás items mantengan sus estilos, solo se dará estilo al primer ítem que se selecciona, y resaltando que no importa el orden que se selecciona los items, siempre se dará un estilo al primer ítem seleccionado.

Llevo un avance en lo cual, solo realizó modificaciones de estilos usando solo CSS, pero tengo un poco el conocimiento que también interviene Javascript para obtener el primer ítem, hasta ahora no tengo idea de como lograr eso.

Muestro la imagen, donde espero aplicar la solución:
[image: Avance del problema]

Como se aprecia, a través de `CSS` logro dar estilos a los items, pero no es lo que espero, porque aplica estilos a todo los items seleccionados.

Muestro el fragmento de código de la estructura del `Componente Combobox`:

```
<v-combobox
   class="specialitySelect"
   v-model="speciality"
   :items="especialidad_items"
   suffix="Especialidad"
   menu-props="auto"
   color="deep-purple darken-1"
   multiple
   single-line
   hide-details
   chips
   box
   ></v-combobox>
```

Código `CSS` para dar estilos a los items del **Lista de especialidades**:

```
.v-menu__content .v-select-list .v-list .v-list__tile--active:first-child {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Espero de su grata ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparto mi solución, espero que sea de gran ayuda para la comunidad, después de tantos días buscando alguna solución logre el objetivo de resolverlo:

```
<v-combobox
  class="specialitySelect"
  v-model="speciality"
  :items="especialidad_items"
  suffix="Especialidad"
  menu-props="auto"
  color="deep-purple darken-1"
  multiple
  single-line
  deletable-chips
  hide-details
  chips
  box
>
  <template v-slot:item="{ index, item, tile, parent }">
    <v-list-tile
      :class="{'styleSpeciality':speciality[0] == item}"
      v-bind="tile.props"
      v-on="tile.on"
      @change="parent.$emit('select', item)"
    >
      <v-list-tile-action>
        <v-checkbox :input-value="tile.props.value" :label="item"></v-checkbox>
      </v-list-tile-action>
    </v-list-tile>
  </template>
</v-combobox>
```

Encontré un problema similar al mio, que me ayudo bastante con mi problema, les comparto el link del `GitHub`:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6376

Les agradezco mucho comunidad, espero que sea de gran ayuda a sus problemas a futuro.